# SQL Server 2014 Log shipping - column error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, log-shipping

I'm trying to set up log shipping between two instances of SQL Server 2014 Dev edition. Backup and copy jobs work flawless, but the restore one keep failing with the following error:

> An error occurred checking the log backup file '\server\file_20151113083854.trn' for secondary database
>   'DB'.(Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.LogShipping)
>   Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.

I'm not able to find out why this keep happening. The same issue occurs for any database I'm trying to set up shipping for. Manual restore of trn file works fine.

I'll be happy for any advice.

Comment: I have not seen such error in logshipping but when you said that when you manually perform restore it works, this makes me think is this something related to account running SQL agent on secondary database. Does this account has *complete* permission to perform restore

Comment: Are the two servers the same exact @@version? I suspect that some DMV might have changed in some service pack / CU.

Comment: Did you use the log shipping wizard to set this up? Help us try to determine the cause by telling us exactly what options you chose when setting it up...

Comment: Thanks for replies! The @@version is identical. I've also compared msdb and master databases and there are no differences. Log shiping from Server2 -> Server1 works fine. The account has all required permissions.